# Change one interactive textbox based on input of another

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an interactive `textbox` in my powerpoint, which I can input text into while presentation mode. I am wondering how I can change the text within another interactive `textbox` on another slide to what I input in the original interactive `textbox`?

I have tried some code in vba:

```vb
ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes("TextBoxNAME2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "TEST"
```

to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your sample

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes("TextBoxNAME2").OLEFormat.Object.Text = "TEST"
```

Or maybe this.
If it is an ActiveX Textbox object you may use event handler:

```
' put this in Slide's module, where You input new value at
' e.g Slide No.1 Module
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    ' You want to update TextBox1 ona Slide 2
    Slide2.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks to be it. Thank you.